# Program type already present: android.support.v4.content.Loader

Tags: android, build.gradle

Here is the error I'm facing while compiling the code:

> Program type already present: android.support.v4.content.Loader
>       Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present: android.support.v4.content.Loader, sources=[Unknown source file], tool
>   name=Optional.of(D8)}

Here is my gradle:

app:dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso-sample:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't need `implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'` since [picasso-sample](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.picasso/picasso-sample/2.5.2) already adds the v4 dependency when compiling (plus two more).

So, try using this then sync:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso-sample:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'

}
```